# Android activity and fragment transition animation

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-transitions, fragmentmanager

I have two activities, both of them will initial a fragment within its activity layout. However, I have trouble adding animation from activity A to activity B. The transition works just fine. Here is some code snippet.

I've tried using overridePending, which basically does nothing. Also, I tried adding custom animation through .setCustomAnimations() in fragmentManager. However, I could only see the second animation slide in but not sliding out. And no animation at all for the first activity.

Main Activity (Activity A):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, new MainFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void gotToCommentActivityWithPostId(String postId){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CommentActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(CommentActivity.POST_ID_KEY, postId);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Main Activity layout:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="yaojungyang.testing.Screens.MainScreen.MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Destination Activity(Activity B):

```
public class CommentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String POST_ID_KEY = "POST_ID_KEY";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.comment_activity_layout);
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(POST_ID_KEY, getIntent().getStringExtra(POST_ID_KEY));
            Fragment fragment = new CommentFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.slide_to_right, R.anim.slide_to_right, R.anim.slide_to_right)
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Destination Activity layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="yaojungyang.testing.Screens.MainScreen.MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by  The transition works just fine.? Please explain it in details what kind of animation you want. It would be great if you upload gif or video around it.

Comment: @jiteshmohite thanks for your reply. I don't need any specific animation, my issue here is the animation is triggered partially or not at all. I tested with a simple slide to left (Acitivty A) slide from right (Acitivty B), which I already have correct animation file. Transaction works fine except there is no animation. Thanks!

Comment: Which means slide_in and slide_out works for you, Problem is animation right? then what kind of animation you want?

Comment: @jiteshmohite
I've tried two different approaches, overridePending and setCustomAnimation. 
Add overridePending doesn't work at all. While setCustomAnimation only partially works. The second activity will slide in from the right but wouldn't go slide back if I press back button. And the first activity simply does not show any animation. I'm certain the animation file is correct as I've used it in other apps.